Prime Subring of a Commutative Ring
I am doing Problem 26 of Chapter 1 in GTM 167 Field and Galois Theory as follows:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. The prime subring of $R$ is the intersection of all subrings of $R$. Show that this intersection is a subring of $R$ that is contained inside all subrings of $R$. Moreover, show that the prime subring of $R$ is equal to $\{n\cdot 1\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $R$.

I have trouble proving the intersection must be inside $\{n\cdot 1\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is one direction of the second part. My idea is to prove the contrapositive: if $r\neq n\cdot 1$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $r\not\in Q$ for some subring $Q\leq R$. I tried to construct some subring $Q$ not containing $r$, but it turns out I don't have a solid idea how to construct subrings indeed.
Can anyone help me with this problem? Also, there is a simple way to construct principal ideals, but are there explicit ways to construct subrings? Any comment is appreciated. Thanks.

@JohnDouma Why do you think it is not true? See also the linked dupe.

@MartinBrandenburg I thought he was saying that it was equal to $\mathbb Z$. I didn't realize before that the definition given does not require characteristic zero. That's why I said to consider $\mathbb Z_2$. But $1+1+1=1=3\cdot 1_{\mathbb Z_2}$ is true.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1_R$. It is straightforward to verify that $\{n\cdot1_R|\ n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ is a subring of $R$, for example as the image of the ring homomorphism
$$\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ R:\ n\ \longmapsto\ n\cdot 1_R.$$
Conversely, every subring $S\subset R$ has $1_R\in S$, hence $n\cdot1_R\in S$ for all $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. This shows that $\{n\cdot1_R|\ n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ is contained in every subring of $R$, so it is the prime subring of $R$.
